# Bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is expected to be of type 'jakarta.servlet.Filter' but was actually of type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Using Spring Boot 3.0.7 and trying to keep things updated I ran into this error and can't figure out what it means.

The dependencies loaded are Spring Security 6.0.9 and the problem exists using either Java 17 or 19 (Spring Boot seems to load Tomcat 10 for the `spring-boot:run` target and has a message about using Java 19.

The application is an OAuth client. The application compiles with no errors and starts up, but you try to hit `localhost:8080` and immediately get the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is expected to be of type 'jakarta.servlet.Filter' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain'

Why would the bean need to be `jakarta.servlet.Filter`?

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>oauth2-sso</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>oauth2-sso</name>
  <description>OAUTH2</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.19</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**SecurityFilterChain**

```java
package com.example.oauth2;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {

    /*
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    */
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login()
            //.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
            ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also add your, application properties

Comment: @user63868 Your packaging is WAR, does it mean that you are deploying the WAR in a servlet container like Tomcat?

Comment: I believe the problem is that @EnableWebSecurity already defines a bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' so redefining that exact bean name caused the problem. Renaming it to 'filterChain' seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation `EnableWebSecurity` in Spring Security 6 (at least 6.0.9 and 6.1.0) imports `WebSecurityConfiguration` which defines a bean of name `springSecurityFilterChain`.

**WebSecurityConfiguration.class**

```java
@Bean(
    name = {"springSecurityFilterChain"}
)
public Filter springSecurityFilterChain() throws Exception {
// ...
```

and other beans depend on it and that it has type `Filter`, so when you change the type of the bean, you're breaking their creation.

Rename your bean using a different method name like `securityFilterChain()` or use a different bean name explicitly `@Bean(name = {"securityFilterChain"}`.